# Why cron job doesn't compile a python file?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

Cron doesn't compile my .py file and I can't get an e-mail from Cron to understand why Cron doesn't work. But if I just run the command `~/t/test.sh` in terminal everything works fine.

Code in the cron:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=mymail@gmail.com
30 0-23 1-31 1-12 0-6 ~/t/test.sh
```

I ty to run a script `test.sh` which has the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/alex/t && python3.8 ./test.py
```

Code in the `test.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime
current_time = datetime.now()
f = open("text.txt", 'w+')
f.write("Hello world! Now is {0}\n".format(current_time))
f.close()
```

I Launched Cron via the `sudo crontab-e` and `crontab-e` commands. I Put Cron in the first line `MAILTO=mymail@gmail.com`.
I Installed `yum install mailx`. I tried adding the command `>/dev/null 2>&1` to Cron, i.e. writing 
`* * * * * ~/t/test.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`
Nothing helps
I Use Ubuntu 18.04
Python3.8.2
Here is what the logs for the `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` command show:

`Apr 30 15:35:01 av CRON[2130]: (alex) CMD (~/t/test.sh)`

`Apr 30 15:35:01 av CRON[2129]: (alex) MAIL (mailer 68 bytes of output put get status 0x004b from MTA#012)`

Has anyone encountered this problem?
Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weakest link in you code is the fact that you invoke the Python 3.8 interpreter without a full path. You invoke bash using a full absolute path, cd to an absolute path, and access your script through a path to the directory into which you cd-ed. Only Python is assuming the existence of some directories in the PATH environment variable.

Try accessing Python 3.8 through the full path to its location.

Answer (score 1):

your test.sh should be something like this: (needs full path)

```
#!/bin/bash
/"location where python is installed"/python/bin/python /home/alex/t/test.py
```